# Scraping Inspect Element and Dynamic Webpage using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, rss

I am trying to get the news content from https://www.thehindu.com/life-and-style/travel/the-embers-of-war/article29202579.ece

Actually, I look for the pattern to get the news content only.. I use the Inspect Element to look for pattern and I found. All the news content are in a div tag which has same class name which is "_yeti_done". My goal is to **scrape** that news content only.

For example,

```
<div id="content-body-14269002-29202579" style="display: block;" class="_yeti_done"> Tom Cruise film is releaseing tommorrow... </div>
```

But when I **scrape** the html content using request library, It only prints with div id but not the class name. Like,

```
<div id="content-body-14269002-29202579"> Tom Cruise film is releaseing tommorrow... </div>
```

After searching answers, I found that the javascript is dynamically load with the html and it is not included in the html when we run this code -

`requests.get('https://www.example.com')`

So, I look the Selenium. Here is my code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = r'C:\Users\softloft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs')
print(driver)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
p_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_yeti_done')
print(p_element.text)
```

And the output -

```
<selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.WebDriver (session="8ea980d0-c403-11e9-83fd-89667b66501a")>
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-bda7935df3c4> in <module>
  6 print(driver)
  7 driver.get("https://www.thehindu.com/business/Industry/hyundai-drives-in-grand-i10-nios-at-499-lakh/article29178286.ece")
----> 8 p_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_yeti_done')
  9 print(p_element.text)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_class_name(self, name)
562             element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo')
563         """
--> 564         return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
565 
566     def find_elements_by_class_name(self, name):
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
979 
980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
323                 response.get('value', None))
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
243 
244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name '_yeti_done'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"99","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:55049","User-Agent":"selenium/3.141.0 (python windows)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"value\": \"_yeti_done\", \"sessionId\": \"8ea980d0-c403-11e9-83fd-89667b66501a\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/8ea980d0-c403-11e9-83fd-89667b66501a/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

How to solve this issue and Is there any way to get the div tag with the class name without considering selenium.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.thehindu.com/life-and-style/travel/the-embers-of-war/article29202579.ece')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([i for i in soup.select_one('[id^=content-body]').get_text().split('\n') if i not in ['','\xa0']])
```